# slickgrid get index of row by it's id

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Is there a way to get the index of a row (row-index in the visible grid) by it's ID, which will also work with a sorted/grouped grid?

I am trying to use the function scrollRowIntoView from Slickgrid, which requires the index of the row. Now my problem is that I know the ID of the row, but not which index the row has in the grid. I also use groups which means I cannot search for the row-index in the data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `dataView.getRowById()` to get the index of a filtered grid or you can use `dataView.getIdxById()` to get the index of the ID from the entire set of data.

Comment: getRowById is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much

Comment: Doesn't work for me, for example i have 26 items in my grid in pages of 25 per page. I go to page 2 and the index should read 0 but it returns 26

Comment: Are you using `getRowById` or `getIdxById`? Do they return different values for you?